# How to post client side multipart/formdata to.net core rest API using wordpress wp_remote_post?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-plugin-creation

Any suggestions how to post a client side file input to php function and then to .NET core web API. The `getCustomHeaderType()` function returns the required headers to my API and `$contentType` is getting read from the client side which gives `"multipart/formdata"` and `boundary`.

**Sample Code Snippet:**
[image]

Comment: Please provide code examples as snippets making use of the `code` markdown.